# How to make autofill input text from a select dropdown box with multiple lines?

Tags: javascript, php, json, select, dropdown

I am trying to have a function where a user can select items they want from a drop-down box, then the price will be displayed in an input box at its side.

I am now facing problem to have the same function in multiple lines. Code are as below:

```
<td class="formiterate" >                                               
    <select id="Employee_ID" name="id[]">
        <option value="">Select one</option>
        <?php
        $st = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_stock");
        $st->execute();
        $rowes = $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach ($rowes as $rowe) {
            ?><option value="<?= $rowe ['id']; ?>"><?= $rowe ['stock_item']; ?> (<?= $rowe ['stock_brand']; ?>)</option><?php
        }
    ?>
    </select>
</td>
<td class="formiterate"><input type="text" name="Last_name[]" id="Last_name"></td>
```

As you can see, when you select from the `Employee_ID`, the item price will reflect in the `Last_name[]` input box.

Whilst the code works fine for a single row, I am not able to iterate the function for multiple row.

Below is my javascript:

```
$(function() { // This code will be executed when DOM is ready
    $('#Employee_ID').change(function() { // When the value for the Employee_ID element change, this will be triggered
        var $row = $(this); // We create an jQuery object with the select inside
        $.post("getData.php", { Employee_ID : $row.val()}, function(json) {
            if (json && json.status) {
                $('#Last_name').val(json.lastname);
            }
        })
    });
})
```

I have tried adding `.closest(".rows")` at `var ($row)= $this`, but noting happened.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: instead of `<select id="Employee_ID"`  use `<select class="Employee_ID"`  and then `$('.Employee_ID')`.Do like this

Comment: id is used for single element event handling  while class is used for group element event-handling

Comment: thanks for the quick response mr @Anant! but now, everytime I select using the dropdown, the value effects other input boxes. I just want the dropdown to only effect the input box which is in line with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example for you (hard code example):-

abc.php:-

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); //check all type of errors
ini_set('display_errors',1);
$rowes = array(0=>array('id'=>1,'stock_item'=>'item1','stock_brand'=>'demo1'),1=>array('id'=>2,'stock_item'=>'item2','stock_brand'=>'demo2'),2=>array('id'=>3,'stock_item'=>'item3','stock_brand'=>'demo3'));
?>
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr style= "float:left;width:100%">
<td class="formiterate" >                                               
    <select class="Employee_ID" name="id[]">
        <option value="">Select one</option>
        <?php
        foreach ($rowes as $rowe) {
            ?><option value="<?= $rowe ['id']; ?>"><?= $rowe ['stock_item']; ?> (<?= $rowe ['stock_brand']; ?>)</option><?php
        }
    ?>
    </select>
</td>
<td class="formiterate"><input type="text" name="Last_name[]" class="Last_name"></td>
</tr>
<tr style= "float:left;width:100%">
    <td class="formiterate" >                                               
        <select class="Employee_ID" name="id[]">
            <option value="">Select one</option>
            <?php
            foreach ($rowes as $rowe) {
                ?><option value="<?= $rowe ['id']; ?>"><?= $rowe ['stock_item']; ?> (<?= $rowe ['stock_brand']; ?>)</option><?php
            }
        ?>
        </select>
    </td>

<td class="formiterate"><input type="text" name="Last_name[]" class="Last_name"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() { // This code will be executed when DOM is ready
    $('.Employee_ID').change(function() { // When the value for the Employee_ID element change, this will be triggered
        var data =  $(this).children(':selected').text();
        console.log(data);
        $(this).parent().next().find('.Last_name').val(data);
    });
})
</script>
</html>
```

Output at my end (after selection from drop-down):- http://prntscr.com/chernw

Note:- put this code to a separate file and run. then you can understand what you have to do, and then change in your code accordingly.thanks.

In your case try like this:-

```
$(function() { // This code will be executed when DOM is ready
    $('.Employee_ID').change(function() { // When the value for the Employee_ID element change, this will be triggered
        var currentseletbox = $(this);
        var data =  $(this).children(':selected').text();
        $.post("getData.php", { Employee_ID : $row.val()}, function(json) {
            if (json && json.status) {
                currentseletbox.parent().next().find('.Last_name').val(json.lastname);
            }
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks Mr @Anant! just one more, how can I just put the price to the Last_name field, instead of putting the same info from the select box?

Comment: @musaspot  i have added some code for you in my answer, but you have to change accordingly, because i don't know how `getData.php` is working and also your actual HTML structure.

Comment: sorry Mr Anant, this is my getData.php

Comment: $st = $pdo->prepare("SELECT stock_item, stock_price FROM tbl_stock WHERE id = '".$_POST['Employee_ID']."'");
$st->execute(array ('id' => $_POST['Employee_ID']));
$data = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo json_encode(array ('status' => true, 'name' => $data ['stock_item'], 'lastname' => $data ['stock_price']));
?>

Comment: @musaspot most welcome. Also heads-off  to your effort. You peoples are great which works hardly to get rid of their problem, not like others who went for sleeping after putting the question on stack.